# How to make Groupby dataframe using list?

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have xyz dataframe like below.

```
x y z
1 2 1
1 2 2 
3 3 1
3 1 2
4 1 2
'''''
9 3 4
```

and I have to make dataframes by x.

```
df1(x=1)
x y z
1 2 3
1 3 3

df2(x=2)
x y z
2 3 3 
2 4 5

dfx(x=n)
x y z
n y z
- - -
```

I know pandas df.groupby("x") makes dataframe by "x".
but there are so many "x" value in my data, so I couldn't define all "x".

Is there any function which makes dataframes using list like groupby(list)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. You can group by multiple columns, but that would give you _more_ groups. Are you saying you want multiple values of `x` in one group?

Comment: @DStanley 
Not in a one group. I want to make dataframes by x values without define x value or call groupby function using a list.
Is it possible?

Comment: so what exactly should be your output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Honestly, I still think this is an X-Y problem.  You asking for a end result, when your issue is more in the way you've setup the problem.   Can you give a more complete picture of what you're trying to achieve with sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

In your case save the df into `dict`

```
d = {x : y for x , y in df.groupby('x')}
d[1]
```

Comment: `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('x'))` still work?

Comment: @ScottBoston yelp ~ but less flexible if the we would like named the value differently ~ :-)

Comment: @BENY Thanks for answer. but what I really want to do thing is call dataframe or dict using list cause I have so many "x" value. Is there any function which can using list?

Comment: XY problem..   Do you want to  do `df[df['x'].isin(some_list_of_x)]`?

Comment: @ScottBoston similar. but its output is one dataframe. I have to split dataframe by x values... am I have to using for loop?

Comment: @Gerrardong I think Ben's answer is exactly what you need (you can have the data for a particular `x` by calling `d[x]`. If that's not what you want, you would need to **really specify** what it is.

Comment: @QuangHoang OK. I have to split dataset by x value and numbering or naming each dataframes. and then, some calculate using each dataframes z value.
So, my goal is like below.

df1(x=1) / calculate done. 
df2(x=2) / calculate done. 
df3(x=2.5) / calculate done. 
dfn(x=xn) / calculate done.